# Installing rosjava_messages fails missing class CircularBlockingDeque

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I was trying to set up a new rosjava environment on Ubuntu 11.04 and ROS electric following the [build guide](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/building.html). Building rosjava_messages fails as org.ros.concurrent.EventDispatcher.java (and others are missing) class org.ros.concurrent.CircularBlockingDequeue.

```
> Building > :rosjava_messages:compileJava > Resolving dependencies     
':rosjava_me:rosjava_messages:compileJava
:rosjava_messages:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:rosjava_messages:classes
:rosjava_messages:jar
:rosjava:compileJava       
/home/andreas/workspace/rosjava_core/rosjava/src/main/java/org/ros/concurrent/EventDispatcher.java:29: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class CircularBlockingDeque
location: class org.ros.concurrent.EventDispatcher<T> private final CircularBlockingDeque<SignalRunnable<T>> events;
```

Interestingly org.ros.concurrent.CircularBlockingQueue is there.

Could somebody please deploy CircularBlockingDequeue?

Thank you!

Best regards,
Andreas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40216/installing-rosjava_messages-fails-missing-class-circularblockingdeque/) by [andreasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/1333/andreasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-07-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andreasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/1333/andreasw/) on 2012-08-28**:
Damons answer  - which I can't comment on Chrome 20.0.1132.47 right now - was correct. Updating rosjava ("rosws remove rosjava_core" etc.) fixed this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe your clone is out of date. Pull and update.

http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/browse/rosjava/src/main/java/org/ros/concurrent/CircularBlockingDeque.java

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1